# Primary Key and Foreign key in same table

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and Entity Framework code-first. I am trying to create a table `Account Master` which will have the details of the customer and columns are as below.

- `Id` as autoincrement primary key
- `Name` as varchar
- `City` as varchar
- `phonenumber` as varchar
- `BrokerId` as int

Now my question is how refer to the `BrokerId` as foreign key to the same table name `Account Master` with the primary key on column `Id`.

Because in my case broker will be also having all this details. As well as it is not necessary that every customer will have broker. Whether I should do like this or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you add a Foreign Key constraint to your CREATE TABLE statement?

```
CONSTRAINT FK_AccMaster_ID FOREIGN KEY (BrokerID)
  REFERENCES AccountMaster(ID)
```

This is a common way to link two tables together.
Unless I am missing something in your question...

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering to the part "Whether I should do like this or not."

Please consider creating two separate tablets User and Broker. Memory wise that's almost same even if User and Broker have same details.

If will provide extensibility to both your tables. Capable of Many to Many relationships.

Also good design implies to let one table represent single entity. To query brokers you don't want to scan your Users and vice versa.